# How to calculate distance travelled by Robot in avr

Tags: avr, atmega, avrdude

Here, I want to calculate distance travelled by robot in atmega 2560? I know the formula distance = Wheel's circumference * motor's rotation in rpm. But I am not getting how to apply this formula for the following problem.

```
What is the approximate distance covered by the robot in 2 seconds, if OCR5AL=OCR5BL=0xB2. Given that, maximum speed at which the motors rotate is 300 rpm and wheels have a radius of 2.8cm.
Where
OCR5AL is Output compare register low value for Left Motor
OCR5BL is Output compare register low value for Right Motor

Maximum speed is attained, when OCR5AL =OCR5BL =0xFF.
```

Answer (score 0):

Motor revolutions per minute (rpm) and wheel revolutions is something different. I do not think your robot's wheels rotate at 300 rpm.
So, in order to be able to calculate the distance, you need to know how many motor revolutions are needed for the wheel to rotate 360 degrees.
This would work fine if you have a stepper motor for instance. Knowing the amount of steps for the wheel to make a full turn gives you a math formula to calculate the distance.
If you want to approach this problem using time measurements, you need to figure out how many seconds and milliseconds it takes for the wheel to turn using different motor speeds.